# How do I alter postgres database to user with a period . in the name?

Tags: postgresql

I have a role name of "john.doe" and I want to alter a table to make him an owner

```
ALTER DATABASE test OWNER TO john.doe;
```

but this returns a syntax error for the "." I've trying wrapping the name in [] and "" but it hasn't helped

Comment: Typically the ownership of a database is to a service account, not a specific person. You would rarely have users with first name or last name. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Have you tried single quotes?

Comment: Or save your self from having to double_quote the role name every time you use it and create the role as `john_doe`.

Comment: @TheImpaler I want to do that because when I type `whoami` I get back "john.doe" so I can have the permission to drop table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(2024-02-18 15:20:22) postgres=# create role "pavel.stehule";
CREATE ROLE
(2024-02-18 15:20:36) postgres=# create database xxx;
CREATE DATABASE
(2024-02-18 15:20:44) postgres=# alter database xxx owner to "pavel.stehule";
ALTER DATABASE
(2024-02-18 15:21:03) postgres=# \l
                                                           List of databases
┌───────────┬───────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────────┐
│   Name    │     Owner     │ Encoding │ Locale Provider │   Collate   │    Ctype    │ ICU Locale │ ICU Rules │   Access privileges   │
╞═══════════╪═══════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ postgres  │ postgres      │ UTF8     │ libc            │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ ∅          │ ∅         │ ∅                     │
│ template0 │ postgres      │ UTF8     │ libc            │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ ∅          │ ∅         │ =c/postgres          ↵│
│           │               │          │                 │             │             │            │           │ postgres=CTc/postgres │
│ template1 │ postgres      │ UTF8     │ libc            │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ ∅          │ ∅         │ =c/postgres          ↵│
│           │               │          │                 │             │             │            │           │ postgres=CTc/postgres │
│ xxx       │ pavel.stehule │ UTF8     │ libc            │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ cs_CZ.UTF-8 │ ∅          │ ∅         │ ∅                     │
└───────────┴───────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────┘
(4 rows)

(2024-02-18 15:21:07) postgres=#
```

For any "strange" identifier, you should to use double quotes.

`[]` is used by MSSQL, but PostgreSQL uses ANSI SQL syntax - string in double quotes - it is exactly same, but by standard.